# Angular 2 filter/search list

Tags: angular

I'm looking for the angular 2 way to do [this](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_lists.asp).

I simply have a list of items, and I want to make an input whos job is to filter the list.

```
<md-input placeholder="Item name..." [(ngModel)]="name"></md-input>

<div *ngFor="let item of items">
{{item.name}}
</div>
```

What's the actual way of doing this in Angular 2? Does that requires a pipe?

Comment: you can create custom pipe for that, which will be best

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: You can use [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html), take a glance at 'HeroSearchComponent' title, or [this](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html) as a reference point.

Comment: This is great example but in my case i'm not using HTTP, I just need to filter it in the client after the list of items have received without any additional responses

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You have to manually filter result based on change of input each time by keeping listener over `input` event. While doing manually filtering make sure you should maintain two copy of variable, one would be original collection copy & second would be `filteredCollection` copy. The advantage for going this way could save your couple of unnecessary filtering on change detection cycle. You may see a more code, but this would be more performance friendly.

**Markup - HTML Template**

```
<md-input #myInput placeholder="Item name..." [(ngModel)]="name" (input)="filterItem(myInput.value)"></md-input>

<div *ngFor="let item of filteredItems">
   {{item.name}}
</div>
```

**Code**

```
assignCopy(){
   this.filteredItems = Object.assign([], this.items);
}
filterItem(value){
   if(!value){
       this.assignCopy();
   } // when nothing has typed
   this.filteredItems = Object.assign([], this.items).filter(
      item => item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1
   )
}
this.assignCopy();//when you fetch collection from server.
```

Comment: This is a nice method, but not working as excepted: The list changes only when the input is blurred, and it's actually remove the items with the name I type instead of showing the items with the name as the input

Comment: That works fine, I Just changed `item.name...` to `!item.name` and it's now searching. the only problem is that if i'm typing for example: "BOX" when there is an item named "BLACK BOX", it will not show it, because "BOX" is the second word (it does not search in all words, only from the first). You have any idea regards this?

Comment: A small tweak to this answer, instead of doing:  `item.property` and only filter on one property you can do: `JSON.stringify(item)` and use all properties in it.

Comment: I am trying the same thing.but it is not working.@TheUnreal .Can you please tell me the exact answer of this.Even i too want to filter by multiple value not only with name.

Answer (score 110):

Search by multiple fields

**Assuming Data:**

```
items = [
  {
    id: 1,
    text: 'First item'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    text: 'Second item'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    text: 'Third item'
  }
];
```

**Markup:**

```
<input [(ngModel)]="query">
<div *ngFor="let item of items | search:'id,text':query">{{item.text}}</div>
```

**Pipe:**

```
import {Pipe, PipeTransform} from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(value, keys: string, term: string) {

    if (!term) return value;
    return (value || []).filter(item => keys.split(',').some(key => item.hasOwnProperty(key) && new RegExp(term, 'gi').test(item[key])));

  }
}
```

*One line for everything!*

Comment: Great answer dude - was wondering if you would know how to attached the `[(ngModel)]="query"` into a radio button? Something like this?
`<input [(ngModel)]="query" type="radio" name="topic.term" [value]="topic.term"/>{{topic.term}}`

Comment: You need to use the 'change' event, like this:`<div *ngFor="let item of items">
<input type="radio"
       name="{{item.text}}"
       [checked]="query == item.text"
       (change)="query = item.text"
       [value]="item.text"/>{{item.text}}
</div>`

Comment: I've created a more specific question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44877635/angular2-filter-pipe-using-radio-buttons-to-filter/

Comment: I needed to create a try/catch around the return statement for cases where the input value is non-regex-able.

Comment: This solution works! And is good for small lists! But on a whole, the Angular team left out these type of Pipes for a reason: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe

Comment: what do the imports looks like? make the example more complete please.

Comment: When running a test with Karma, I get this error: `TypeError: (value || []).filter is not a function`. Do you know what could be wrong?

Comment: by far the better solution!

Comment: It works great! But I have a question, How can I get the length of filtered array?

Comment: @MosheQuantz Can you please tell me which is more efficient? Pipes or filtering array through normal function on change of ngModel query value? and why?

Comment: @MosheQuantz How can I apply this pipe on  *ngFor="
              let dataConceptList of selectDataConceptForm.controls[
                'dataOwnerList'
              ].controls | search:'id,text':query";
              let i = index "
          > I'm getting value as FormControl

Answer (score 15):

HTML

```
<input [(ngModel)] = "searchTerm" (ngModelChange) = "search()"/>
<div *ngFor = "let item of items">{{item.name}}</div>
```

Component

```
search(): void {
    let term = this.searchTerm;
    this.items = this.itemsCopy.filter(function(tag) {
        return tag.name.indexOf(term) >= 0;
    }); 
}
```

Note that **this.itemsCopy** is equal to **this.items** and should be set before doing the search.

Comment: what tag mean ?

Comment: @MuhammedMoussa "tag" is the function's callback variable, in this case, the item object. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: I like this reply because it's not using a pipe, it's using Javascript filter

Answer (score 5):

data

```
names = ['Prashobh','Abraham','Anil','Sam','Natasha','Marry','Zian','karan']
```

You can achieve this by creating a simple pipe

```
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="queryString" id="search" placeholder="Search to type">
```

Pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'FilterPipe',
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, input: string) {
        if (input) {
            input = input.toLowerCase();
            return value.filter(function (el: any) {
                return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
            })
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

This will filter the result based on the search term

[More Info](http://www.angulartutorial.net/2017/03/simple-search-using-pipe-in-angular-2.html)

Comment: hi, can you please tell how I can do this with this array: [{"id":"1","name":"aa"},{"id":"2","name":"bb"}...]. I have asked a question this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44180587/angular2-auto-suggester, it will be helpfull if you can answer. Thanks in advance

Comment: Change this line accordingly   return el.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;
In your case el.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(input) > -1;

Answer (score 5):

In angular 2 we don't have pre-defined filter and order by as it was with AngularJs, we need to create it for our requirements. It is time killing but we need to do it, (see No FilterPipe or OrderByPipe). In this article we are going to see how we can create filter called pipe in angular 2 and sorting feature called Order By. Let's use a simple dummy json data array for it. Here is the json we will use for our example

First we will see how to use the pipe (filter) by using the search feature:

Create a component with name category.component.ts

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-category',
      templateUrl: './category.component.html'
    })
    export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit {

      records: Array<any>;
      isDesc: boolean = false;
      column: string = 'CategoryName';
      constructor() { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.records= [
          { CategoryID: 1,  CategoryName: "Beverages", Description: "Coffees, teas" },
          { CategoryID: 2,  CategoryName: "Condiments", Description: "Sweet and savory sauces" },
          { CategoryID: 3,  CategoryName: "Confections", Description: "Desserts and candies" },
          { CategoryID: 4,  CategoryName: "Cheeses",  Description: "Smetana, Quark and Cheddar Cheese" },
          { CategoryID: 5,  CategoryName: "Grains/Cereals", Description: "Breads, crackers, pasta, and cereal" },
          { CategoryID: 6,  CategoryName: "Beverages", Description: "Beers, and ales" },
          { CategoryID: 7,  CategoryName: "Condiments", Description: "Selishes, spreads, and seasonings" },
          { CategoryID: 8,  CategoryName: "Confections", Description: "Sweet breads" },
          { CategoryID: 9,  CategoryName: "Cheeses",  Description: "Cheese Burger" },
          { CategoryID: 10, CategoryName: "Grains/Cereals", Description: "Breads, crackers, pasta, and cereal" }
         ];
         // this.sort(this.column);
      }
    }
```

```html
<div class="col-md-12">
  <table class="table table-responsive table-hover">
    <tr>
      <th >Category ID</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Description</th>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngFor="let item of records">
      <td>{{item.CategoryID}}</td>
      <td>{{item.CategoryName}}</td>
      <td>{{item.Description}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

2.Nothing special in this code just initialize our records variable with a list of categories, two other variables isDesc and column are declared which we will use for sorting latter. At the end added this.sort(this.column); latter we will use, once we will have this method.

Note templateUrl: './category.component.html', which we will create next to show the records in tabluar format.

For this create a HTML page called category.component.html, whith following code:

3.Here we use ngFor to repeat the records and show row by row, try to run it and we can see all records in a table.

Search - Filter Records

Say we want to search the table by category name, for this let's add one text box to type and search

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-md-6" >
    <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText" 
           class="form-control" placeholder="Search By Category" />
  </div>
</div>
```

5.Now we need to create a pipe to search the result by category because filter is not available as it was in angularjs any more.

Create a file category.pipe.ts and add following code in it.

```js
    import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';
    @Pipe({ name: 'category' })
    export class CategoryPipe implements PipeTransform {
      transform(categories: any, searchText: any): any {
        if(searchText == null) return categories;

        return categories.filter(function(category){
          return category.CategoryName.toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1;
        })
      }
    }
```

6.Here in transform method we are accepting the list of categories and search text to search/filter record on the list. Import this file into our category.component.ts file, we want to use it here, as follows:

```js
import { CategoryPipe } from './category.pipe';
@Component({      
  selector: 'app-category',
  templateUrl: './category.component.html',
  pipes: [CategoryPipe]   // This Line       
})
```

7.Our ngFor loop now need to have our Pipe to filter the records so change it to this.You can see the output in image below

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnXJb.png)

Comment: code is working but you missed one step for calling filter `<tr *ngFor="let item of records | search : searchText">` pls add this inside .html file. Can you provide another solution for multilevel filtering?

Answer (score 2):

You can also create a [search pipe](https://gist.github.com/ranakrunal9/092d6b930ede855e59e82c0f429fd562) to filter results:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name : 'searchPipe',
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(value, key: string, term: string) {
    return value.filter((item) => {
      if (item.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        if (term) {
          let regExp = new RegExp('\\b' + term, 'gi');
          return regExp.test(item[key]);
        } else {
          return true;
        }
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Use pipe in HTML :

```
<md-input placeholder="Item name..." [(ngModel)]="search" ></md-input>
<div *ngFor="let item of items | searchPipe:'name':search ">
  {{item.name}}
</div>
```

Comment: Typing any search name don't show any items in the list

Answer (score 1):

[Pipes](https://angular.io/guide/pipes) in Angular 2+ are a great way to transform and format data right from your templates.

Pipes allow us to change data inside of a template; i.e. filtering, ordering, formatting dates, numbers, currencies, etc. A quick example is you can transfer a string to lowercase by applying a simple filter in the template code.

List of Built-in Pipes from [API List](https://angular.io/api?type=pipe) <sup>[Examples](https://alligator.io/angular/built-in-pipes-angular/)</sup>

```
{{ user.name | uppercase }}
```

---

Example of Angular version 4.4.7. `ng version`

---

[**Custom Pipes**](https://alligator.io/angular/custom-pipes-angular/) which accepts multiple arguments.

```
HTML « *ngFor="let student of students | jsonFilterBy:[searchText, 'name'] "
TS   « transform(json: any[], args: any[]) : any[] { ... }
```

Filtering the content using a Pipe « `json-filter-by.pipe.ts`

```javascript
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'jsonFilterBy' })
@Injectable()
export class JsonFilterByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(json: any[], args: any[]) : any[] {
    var searchText = args[0];
    var jsonKey = args[1];

    // json = undefined, args = (2) [undefined, "name"]
    if(searchText == null || searchText == 'undefined') return json;
    if(jsonKey    == null || jsonKey    == 'undefined') return json;

    // Copy all objects of original array into new Array.
    var returnObjects = json;
    json.forEach( function ( filterObjectEntery ) {

      if( filterObjectEntery.hasOwnProperty( jsonKey ) ) {
        console.log('Search key is available in JSON object.');

        if ( typeof filterObjectEntery[jsonKey] != "undefined" && 
        filterObjectEntery[jsonKey].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1 ) {
            // object value contains the user provided text.
        } else {
            // object didn't match a filter value so remove it from array via filter
            returnObjects = returnObjects.filter(obj => obj !== filterObjectEntery);
        }
      } else {
        console.log('Search key is not available in JSON object.');
      }

    })
    return returnObjects;
  }
}
```

Add to **`@NgModule`** « Add **`JsonFilterByPipe`** to your declarations list in your module; if you forget to do this you'll get an error no provider for **`jsonFilterBy`**. *If you add to module then it is available to all the component's of that module.*

```javascript
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
    FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [ StudentDetailsService ],
  declarations: [
    UsersComponent, UserComponent,

    JsonFilterByPipe,
  ],
  exports : [UsersComponent, UserComponent]
})
export class UsersModule {
    // ...
}
```

File Name: `users.component.ts` and `StudentDetailsService` is created from [this link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-service-example?file=app%2Fservice%2Fmock-students.ts).

```javascript
import { MyStudents } from './../../services/student/my-students';
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { StudentDetailsService } from '../../services/student/student-details.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-users',
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './users.component.css' ],

  providers:[StudentDetailsService]
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy  {

  students: MyStudents[];
  selectedStudent: MyStudents;

  constructor(private studentService: StudentDetailsService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.loadAllUsers();
  }
  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    // ONDestroy to prevent memory leaks
  }

  loadAllUsers(): void {
    this.studentService.getStudentsList().then(students => this.students = students);
  }

  onSelect(student: MyStudents): void {
    this.selectedStudent = student;
  }

}
```

File Name: `users.component.html`

```html
<div>
    <br />
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-6" >
            Filter by Name: 
            <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="searchText" 
                   class="form-control" placeholder="Search By Category" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <h2>Present are Students</h2>
    <ul class="students">
    <li *ngFor="let student of students | jsonFilterBy:[searchText, 'name'] " >
        <a *ngIf="student" routerLink="/users/update/{{student.id}}">
            <span class="badge">{{student.id}}</span> {{student.name | uppercase}}
        </a>
    </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  Tried several of the above examples and this is the one that worked for me

Answer (score 1):

**try this**
*html code*

```
<md-input #myInput placeholder="Item name..." [(ngModel)]="name"></md-input>

<div *ngFor="let item of filteredItems | search: name">
   {{item.name}}
</div>
```

*use search pipe*

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'search'
})
export class SearchPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(value: any, args?: any): any {

    if(!value)return null;
    if(!args)return value;

    args = args.toLowerCase();

    return value.filter(function(item){
        return JSON.stringify(item).toLowerCase().includes(args);
    });
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight modification to @Mosche answer, **for handling if there exist no filter element.**

**TS**:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
    name: 'filterFromList'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
    public transform(value, keys: string, term: string) {

        if (!term) {
            return value
        }
        let res = (value || []).filter((item) => keys.split(',').some(key => item.hasOwnProperty(key) && new RegExp(term, 'gi').test(item[key])));
        return res.length ? res : [-1];

    }
}
```

> Now, in your HTML you can check via '-1' value, for no results.

**HTML**:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of list | filterFromList: 'attribute': inputVariableModel">
            <mat-list-item *ngIf="item !== -1">
                <h4 mat-line class="inline-block">
                 {{item}}
                </h4>
            </mat-list-item>
            <mat-list-item *ngIf="item === -1">
                No Matches
            </mat-list-item>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This code nearly worked for me...but I wanted a multiple element filter so my mods to the filter pipe are below:

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({ name: 'jsonFilterBy' })
@Injectable()
export class JsonFilterByPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(json: any[], args: any[]): any[] {
    const searchText = args[0];
    const jsonKey = args[1];
    let jsonKeyArray = [];

    if (searchText == null || searchText === 'undefined') { return json; }

    if (jsonKey.indexOf(',') > 0) {
        jsonKey.split(',').forEach( function(key) {
            jsonKeyArray.push(key.trim());
        });
    } else {
        jsonKeyArray.push(jsonKey.trim());
    }

    if (jsonKeyArray.length === 0) { return json; }

    // Start with new Array and push found objects onto it.
    let returnObjects = [];
    json.forEach( function ( filterObjectEntry ) {

        jsonKeyArray.forEach( function (jsonKeyValue) {
            if ( typeof filterObjectEntry[jsonKeyValue] !== 'undefined' &&
            filterObjectEntry[jsonKeyValue].toLowerCase().indexOf(searchText.toLowerCase()) > -1 ) {
                // object value contains the user provided text.
                returnObjects.push(filterObjectEntry);
                }
            });

    });
    return returnObjects;
  }
}
```

Now, instead of

```
jsonFilterBy:[ searchText, 'name']
```

you can do

```
jsonFilterBy:[ searchText, 'name, other, other2...']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<md-input placeholder="Item name..." [(ngModel)]="name" (keyup)="filterResults()"></md-input>

<div *ngFor="let item of filteredValue">
{{item.name}}
</div>

  filterResults() {
    if (!this.name) {
      this.filteredValue = [...this.items];
    } else {
      this.filteredValue = [];
      this.filteredValue = this.items.filter((item) => {
        return item.name.toUpperCase().indexOf(this.name.toUpperCase()) > -1;
      });
    }
 }
```

Don't do any modification on 'items' array(list of items from which results are filtered).
When searched item 'name' is empty return the complete list of 'items', if not compare the 'name' with every 'name' in the 'items ' array and filter out only the name that is present in 'items' array and store it in the 'filteredValue'.

Answer (score 0):

Currently [ng2-search-filter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng2-search-filter) simplify this works.

By directive

```
<tr *ngFor="let item of items | filter:searchText">
  <td>{{item.name}}</td>
</tr>
```

Or programmatically

```
let itemsFiltered = new Ng2SearchPipe().transform(items, searchText);
```

Practical example: https://angular-search-filter.stackblitz.io