# How to use filters of Angular 1.x in Angular 2?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, typescript

I designed few custom filters in Angular 1.x and I want to reuse the same in Angular 2. Can someone please tell me if it is possible to use custom filters of Angular 1.x in Angular 2?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 filter/search list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678206/angular-2-filter-search-list)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular 1 & Angular 2 is totally different. Don't confuse with both. You can use logic but not codes(code style is different).

https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/ajs-quick-reference.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link. Its very helpful