# Contact list with search filter

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular6, angular-pipe

I want to make contact list with search filter on the top like this

Many people are saying we have to do it by calling web API's, Can't i do it manually by creating some name in an arrays.I have tried this link too

```
    https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678206/angular-2-filter-search-list
```

still no result.There is no components found in material also(https://material.angular.io/components), some site mentioned that we have to use pipes for filter, pipes are very new concept for me.How can i achieve?

Comment: Well ["some sites" are wrong](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe). I suggest you filter you content at component level with `Array.prototype.filter`, and bind the function to the `(input)` event listener of your input.

Comment: I think angular Pipes is used to clean the data, not for search, for example convert date object into some string format,Using a pipe u can  take date object as argument, and return as a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vchhay

using filter you can use input to achieve this.

***Edited with Pipes:***

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vchhay

**Using pipes is really simple.**

Comment: yes, but if my code help you, mark my answer as correct atleast.

Comment: you can improve so much this code appliying this on a pipe. Is the right form to doing this, but no one going code your app for you, you can do this easily with this base code.

Comment: Edited to use pipes.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Angular 6, than pipes that filter are not supported anymore. You would have to write your own pipe.

[See here](https://angular.io/guide/pipes)

Angular doesn't provide pipes for filtering or sorting lists. Developers familiar with AngularJS know these as filter and orderBy. There are no equivalents in Angular.

I would go with one of these options:

1. [Angular Tutorial](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#search-by-name), build a method inside your component that will filter the array. Similar to the suggestion by Ankit Sharma.
2. Filter in template with [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_filters.asp). (not recommended, but rather simple) This is a small example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container mt-3">
  <h2>Filterable List</h2>
  <p>Type something in the input field to search the list for specific items:</p>  
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <br>
  <ul class="list-group" id="myList">
    <li class="list-group-item">First item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Second item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Third item</li>
    <li class="list-group-item">Fourth</li>
  </ul>  
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList li").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: **Please DON'T use jQuery with Angular.**

Comment: Yeah, i wouldn't recommend it as well, but is simple to set up

Answer (score 0):

You may use the `filter` ([refer this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)) method of `Array` to filter out your list and listen to `(keyup)` event of the `input` and then call a function to filter your list.

In Angular.js (v1), there used to be a filter (now known as pipe) that used to do the same thing. However long gone are the days, when Angular provided such a functionality. This is majorly due to the reason that the pipes (Angular 2 onwards) are either pure / impure. By default all pipes provided by Angular are pure and hence there is no filterPipe anymore.

You may refer to the below link to get some understanding why Angular team removed such a functionality:-

> https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe