# Unable to apply search filter for data present in json file

Tags: json, angular, angular6, angular-pipe

This is my (custom.component.html) file

```
    <input ng-model="searchText" placeholder="&nbsp;&nbsp;Enter the name" 
            class="seacrh-field"><br><br>

     <mat-card class="example-card" *ngFor="let spaceScreen of 
               spaceScreens; 
                   let i = index">

        <mat-card-header>
           <div mat-card-avatar class="example-header-image" >
                <img mat-card-image class="list-img" src=" 
              {{spaceScreen?.img}}" >
          </div>

          <mat-card-content class="names">{{ spaceScreen?.name }} 
          </mat-card-content>
       </mat-card-header>

    </mat-card>
```

This is (custom.component.ts) file

```
            import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
            import { Http } from '@angular/http'; 
            import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'

            @Component({
              selector: 'ylb-customer',
              templateUrl: './customer.component.html',
              styleUrls: ['./customer.component.css']
            })
            export class CustomerComponent  {

              spaceScreens: Array<any>;

              constructor(private http:Http){
                this.http.get('assets/app.json').pipe(
                  map(response => response.json().screenshots)
              ).subscribe(res => this.spaceScreens = res);
                }


            }
```

This is(app.json) file present in assets folder

```
            {   
        "screenshots":[ 

                    {
                        "img":"assets/img/json_2.jpg",
                        "name":"Virat Kohli"
                    },

                    {
                        "img":"assets/img/json_2.jpg",
                        "name":"Joe Root"
                    },

                    {
                        "img":"assets/img/json_2.jpg",
                        "name":"Adam Gilchrist"
                    },
                    {
                        "img":"assets/img/json_2.jpg",
                        "name":"Kevin Peterson"
                    },

                    {
                        "img":"assets/img/json_2.jpg",
                        "name":"Misbhah-Ul-Hak"
                    },

                    {
                        "img":"assets/img/json_2.jpg",
                        "name":"ABD Develliers"
                    },
                    {
                        "img":"assets/img/json_2.jpg",
                        "name":"Ben stokes"
                    },

                    {
                        "img":"assets/img/json_2.jpg",
                        "name":"Chris Gayle"
                    }

            ]        
        }
```

Everything is working fine,how can i apply search filter(like contact list in mobile)to data present in app.json file.Tried many method,still no result.How can i achieve easily using custom pipes

Comment: Could you explain what you have tried already?

Comment: Possible duplicate of (https://stackoverflow.com/q/40678206/9775003)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2 filter/search list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678206/angular-2-filter-search-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Angular 1 most people did filtering with pipes.  This was pointed out by **trichetriche** in the comments of the other answer and is correct.  Problem is allowing this behavior leads to poor performance because every digest cycle would trigger the filtering (and this happens a lot).  So in Angular 2+ they want you to filter the results in the components and store the results in an array, then just use *ngFor="myFilteredArray".

**First** setup binding on your input so we can get what the user wants to search for.

```
//Use this method if you want to track name for more than a filter.  
//Result will be stored in name var
<input type="text" [(ngModel)]="name" (ngModelChange)="onNameChange()">
//Use this if you don't need to track the name text for anything else.
<input type="text" (input)="onNameChangeInput($event.target.value)">

<div *ngFor="let s of filteredScreenshots">
  {{s | json}}
</div>
```

**Second** add change functions to your component.ts

You are going to want a library like lodash or underscore.
If you don't have lodash install with - https://lodash.com/docs

`npm install lodash`

*component.ts*

```
import * as _ from 'lodash';

export class CustomerComponent  {

    spaceScreens: Array<any>;
    filteredScreens = [];
    name: string;

    constructor(private http:Http){
        this.http.get('assets/app.json').pipe(
              map(response => response.json().screenshots)
          )
          .subscribe(res => {
              this.spaceScreens = res; //this is what we filter against
              this.filteredScreens = res; //init with full list
         });
    }

    onNameChange() {
        this.filteredScreens = _.filter(this.spaceScreens, (screenshot) => {
             const name = screenshot['name'];
             const filteredName = this.name.toUpperCase();
             return name === undefined ? false : name.toUpperCase().startsWith(filteredName);
        });
    }

    onNameChangeInput(filteredName: string) {
        this.filteredScreens = _.filter(this.spaceScreens, (screenshot) => {
            const name = screenshot['name'];
            filteredName = filteredName.toUpperCase();
            return name === undefined ? false : name.toUpperCase().startsWith(filteredName);
       });
    }
}
```

You only need to go with one input and one change function, they are named appropriately so it's obvious which method goes with each input.

Edit:
I forgot to mention this solution is case insensitive, since generally on a search like this you don’t care about case. If you want it to be case sensitive then remove the .toUpperCase().

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.I am getting this error now

Comment: error TS2339: Property 'screenshots' does not exist on type 'CustomerComponent'.

Comment: src/app/customer/customer.component.ts(29,38): error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'CustomerComponent'.
src/app/customer/customer.component.ts(35,44): error TS2339: Property 'screenshots' does not exist on type 'CustomerComponent'.

Comment: Sorry, I changed the  component variable name screenshots to spaceScreens last minute and didn't update the filter.  Answer updated.  Issue was with the _.filter(this.screenshots) should have been _.filter(this.spaceScreens.

Comment: Thanks,that error was cleared.Still left with this       error TS2339: Property 'name' does not exist on type 'CustomerComponent'.

Comment: Updated answer again, need to declare name: string; in the component since ngModel is binding to it.

Comment: Tried with  one input and one change function only,still not working.

Comment: If you are using ngModel input make sure you are using the onNameChange.  I would also add a console.log(this.name) before the _.filter() and add a console.table(this.filteredScreens) after the _.filter. After you validate the function is firing and working. Make sure your ngFor is using the filteredScreens array and not spaceScreens array.

Comment: You are awesome,Thanks for your all replies.

Comment: @VenetianVillage you’re welcome :) glad you got it working

Comment: How can i apply search for  last name of the name string,i mean suppose i want to search chris gayle,how can i search it by typing only gayle.I know you helped lot,but this requirement i must finish.

Comment: If you only want to match on last name then you will have to update your json with firstName, and lastName.  Otherwise you could use the .include() instead of .startsWith().
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_includes.asp