# Search filter in custom list component

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-custom-component

I am creating a custom list component with a search in my angular project. This component will take itemList as input and list the items based on the same. I would like to plug in a search bar to this component so that the user can search the items from the list.

I have created a pipe as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678206/angular-2-filter-search-list) by Moshe Quantz for search. this is not working with the component i have created. please find the [stackblitz](https://angular-q3lpjr.stackblitz.io) code snippet here.

Comment: Please create a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on stackblitz.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The search pipe takes 3 params.

1. Value: it is list of items on which you want to perform search.
2. keys: it is string with comma separated values. This string(s) is used to specify the field(s) of value on which search must be performed.
3. query: The actual search term which user types in textbox

.

```
  public transform(value, keys: string, term: string)
```

so the the problem is your object fields differ from the on used in other example. Simply update those and it will work fine.

```
<input placeholder="search text goes here" [(ngModel)]="query">
<div *ngFor="let item of listItem | search:'title,date,status':query">
    <app-list-card [item]="item"></app-list-card>    
</div>
```

Working example on [stackbliz.com](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-61pgjx?file=src/app/search.pipe.ts)

Please do note that using Pipe in such a way is very poor practice and may [cause performance issue](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe) as the number of items in list increases.