# How to search element through API in angular?

Tags: angular

I have implemented angular template and I am showing iterative data in div through *ngFor. And I want to search particular element. I am trying with filter but it is not working for me. May be I am showing data through API call that's why search is not working. I am new in Angular 2.

> API:https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component,OnInit  } from '@angular/core';
import { ApiService } from './api.service';
import { DatePipe} from './date.pipe';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
  title = 'demo';
  searchText;
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService){}
  ngOnInit(){
    this.apiService.apiCall().subscribe((data)=>{
      console.warn("get",data.results);
      this.data=data;     
    })
  }

}
```

**app.component.html**

```
 <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-3" style="background-color: black;" *ngFor="let data of data.results">
      <div class="col-md-12 " style="background-color:rgba(125, 123, 123, 0.83);padding:0px;margin-top:20px;">
        <div class="text-image">
          <img [src]="data.image" class="img-fluid" style="border-radius: 5px 5px 5px 5px;">
          <div class="bottom-left text-left" style="background-color: #0c0c0c;padding:13px;">
            <div>{{data.name}}</div>
            <div style="font-size:12px">
              <span>id: {{data.id}} </span> -  <span>  created 
                {{data.created | DateFilter}} years ago</span>
            </div>            
          </div>
        </div>
        <table style="font-size: 11px;">
          <tr>
            <td style="color:rgb(197, 194, 194)"><strong>STATUS</strong></td>
            <td style="color: #ea8c2a;"><strong>{{data.status}}</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="color:rgb(197, 194, 194)"><strong>SPECIES</strong></td>
            <td style="color: #ea8c2a;"><strong>{{data.species}}</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="color:rgb(197, 194, 194)"><strong>GENDER</strong></td>
            <td style="color: #ea8c2a;"><strong>{{data.gender}}</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="color:rgb(197, 194, 194)"><strong>ORIGIN</strong></td>
            <td style="color: #ea8c2a;"><strong>{{data.origin.name}}</strong></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td style="color:rgb(197, 194, 194)"><strong>lOCATION</strong> </td>
            <td style="color: #ea8c2a;"><strong>{{data.location.name}}</strong></td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**api.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ApiService {

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}
  apiCall(){
      return this.httpClient.get('https://rickandmortyapi.com/api/character/');
  }
}
```

s**tyle.css**

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  th, td {
    padding: 8px;
    text-align: left;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ddd;
  }
  .text-image {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
  }
  
  .bottom-left {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    opacity: 0.8;
    width:100%
    
  }
```

Suppose I will search by name then it should appear only particular div.

I checked this link but it is not working:
[Angular 2 filter/search list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40678206/angular-2-filter-search-list)

Comment: Where's the search/filter related code that you've tried? Add it even if it doesn't work.

Comment: Yea I tried, But not effective. I have created one custome pipe. called filterlist.pipe.ts. When I am going in put along with *ngFor. But not working. In pipe it is going in if condition  transform(value1: any, args?: any): any {
    if(!args)
    {
        console.log("------------",value1);
        return value1;
    }
   
    return value1.filter(
      item => item.first_name.toLowerCase().indexOf(args.toLowerCase()) > -1
   );
  }

Comment: Add this and the related HTML to the question.

Comment: Do u want serverside filter or clientside one ?

Comment: Anyone. Only after input search should happpend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gcxygx)

You can solve with pipe

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'filter'
})
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {

 
 public transform(value: any[], filterText: string) {

    return filterText.length>3 ? value.filter(x=> x.name.toLowerCase().includes(filterText.toLowerCase())): value
  }
}
```